# how to debug yapsy plugin?

Tags: python, debugging

Whenever some minor mistakes or error  happens syntatical or runtime error the yapsy plugin throws the error **"No handlers could be found for logger "yapsy"**

It does not highlight the error where and why has happened and the error finding becomes hard job. If you have any experienced with yapsy plugin manager advice me some way to handle the yapsy errors

Answer (score 0):

From [No handlers could be found for logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188270/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger), try simply adding:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

there are really two problems in what you describe so let me give a 2-part answer.

1/ For your main question, aobut how to debug yapsy:  you should set the log level to DEBUG which is explained in [the troubleshooting section of the doc](http://yapsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advices.html#use-the-logging-system).

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('yapsy').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

2/ The error message you report is quite unexpected and suggest that something is wrong with the setup. The **init**.py file of yapsy sets up the logger so I'm really not sure of what's happening. I would recommend you fill a bug on yapsy's forge there, if possible with more details, like sample code: https://sourceforge.net/p/yapsy/bugs/?source=navbar

Comment: imported and logging set but this really does no show up any error message on terminals

Comment: I have the same issue, and this does not resolve it.

Comment: Yes @tbenst just make  sure all the code syntax error does not occur. that is the only solutions. the debugger wont throw errors that are not associated with yapsy

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung, see my answer below that solves the question.