# Why does calling logging.info change what my logger prints?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to get Python to log stuff and, despite having read over the [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#) and [how-to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), I don't understand its behavior.

I set the global log level and then tried logging something:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
print("Initially should be warn: %d" % logger.getEffectiveLevel())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print("Logger level: %d" % logger.getEffectiveLevel())

logger.info("Maybe I am printed?")
```

But running `python my_script.py` just prints:

```
Initially should be warn: 30
Logger level: 10
```

However, if I add a line `logging.info` call, e.g.,

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
print("Initially should be warn: %d" % logger.getEffectiveLevel())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print("Logger level: %d" % logger.getEffectiveLevel())

logging.info("I am printed")
logger.info("Maybe I am printed?")
```

then the logging all shows up:

```
Initially should be warn: 30
Logger level: 10
INFO:root:I am printed
INFO:root:Maybe I am printed?
```

What is `logging.info` doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example will actually warn you that *No handlers could be found for logger "root"* ([see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188270/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger). This is because, as suggested, you did not define any handler for `logger`.

Here is the implementation of `logging.info`:

```
def info(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Log a message with severity 'INFO' on the root logger.
    """
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        basicConfig()
    root.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, when no handler is found, it will call `basicConfig` which will take also care of initializing a default handler, thus fixing the logging in your following statements.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `logging.info` is configuring the logging handler and formatter so it can output the logs. If you want to do that yourself the following code will set it up:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info("boo")
```

There are more details on configuring logging in the [configuring logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) section of the tutorial.

The code that `logging.info` calls to setup logging is available in [github.com](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/97d7e65dfed1d42d40d9bc2f630af56240555f02/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1755). It essentially just create the handler if no handlers exist.